# '' RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop '' once function is called

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, tkinter

So im writing my first program and it is 2000+ lines, and i have this function down below that works on its own, but when i past it in the program and once i call the function via a button i get the error above. The function sits within other functions and is a few indents in which i assume is the reason it doesn't work. The function is pasted below (shitty code with unnecessary lines) but i dont think i can paste my 2000 line program here. Im not even sure i provided enough info so that i can get help, but the question is really, am i getting this error because the thread is called from the wrong place?

```
from PIL import ImageTk,Image
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import threading


root = Tk()

root.title("AutoInspect")
root.geometry("1110x590")
root.iconbitmap(r"icon.ico")
root.configure(background="#333333")



bromsdata = open("lufttryck.txt", "r")
tasksleft = 3
tasksgodk = 0
tasksundk = 0


def starta_i1():
    toplabel = Label(root, text="blablabla", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), width=39, background="#414141",
                     foreground="#878AFF")
    toplabel.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=40, ipadx=40)

    procent_label = Label(root, text="0%", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 50), height=1, width=22, background="#414141",
                          foreground="#878AFF")
    procent_label.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=0, ipadx=40)

    task_label = Label(root, text="...", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=2, width=39, background="#414141",
                       foreground="#878AFF")
    task_label.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=0, ipadx=40)

    status_godk = Label(root, text="Godkända: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=12,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_godk.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=1, pady=40, sticky="w")

    status_undk = Label(root, text="Underkända: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=16,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_undk.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=1, pady=40, padx=40)

    status_kvar = Label(root, text="Kvar: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=10,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_kvar.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=1, pady=40, sticky="e")

    avsluta = Button(root, text="AVSLUTA", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), cursor="hand2", height=0, width=39,
                     border=0, foreground="#878AFF", background="#414141", activebackground="#999999",
                     activeforeground="#D3D5FF", relief="sunken")
    avsluta.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=(0, 40), ipadx=40)
    global tasksleft
    global tasksgodk
    global tasksundk
    tasksleft = 3
    tasksgodk = 0
    tasksundk = 0
    procent_label.config(text="0%")
    task_label.configure(text="Just nu pågår: 4.0.1 Kontroll av Bromscylindertryck...")
    status_kvar.configure(text="Kvar: " + str(tasksleft))
    status_godk.configure(text="Godkända: " + str(tasksgodk))
    status_undk.configure(text="Underkända: " + str(tasksundk))
    time.sleep(1)
    punkt1_i1()


def punkt1_i1():
    toplabel = Label(root, text="blablabla", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), width=39, background="#414141",
                     foreground="#878AFF")
    toplabel.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=40, ipadx=40)

    procent_label = Label(root, text="0%", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 50), height=1, width=22, background="#414141",
                          foreground="#878AFF")
    procent_label.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=0, ipadx=40)

    task_label = Label(root, text="...", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=2, width=39, background="#414141",
                       foreground="#878AFF")
    task_label.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=0, ipadx=40)

    status_godk = Label(root, text="Godkända: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=12,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_godk.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=1, pady=40, sticky="w")

    status_undk = Label(root, text="Underkända: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=16,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_undk.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=1, pady=40, padx=40)

    status_kvar = Label(root, text="Kvar: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=10,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_kvar.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=1, pady=40, sticky="e")

    avsluta = Button(root, text="AVSLUTA", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), cursor="hand2", height=0, width=39,
                     border=0, foreground="#878AFF", background="#414141", activebackground="#999999",
                     activeforeground="#D3D5FF", relief="sunken")
    avsluta.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=(0, 40), ipadx=40)
    global tasksleft
    global tasksgodk
    global tasksundk
    for line in bromsdata:
        if "bromscylindertryck" in line:
            break
    bromsindex = (line.find("="))
    bromstryckindex = int(bromsindex) + 1
    bt = line[bromstryckindex:]
    bt = int(bt.strip())
    print(bt)
    if bt > 41:
        print("fail")
        tasksundk = tasksundk + 1
    elif bt < 36:
        print("fail")
        tasksundk = tasksundk + 1
    else:
        print("Success")
        tasksgodk = tasksgodk + 1
    tasksleft = tasksleft - 1

    task_label.configure(text="Just nu pågår: 4.0.2 Kontroll av Huvudledningstryck...")
    procent_label.config(text="33%")
    status_kvar.configure(text="Kvar: " + str(tasksleft))
    status_godk.configure(text="Godkända: " + str(tasksgodk))
    status_undk.configure(text="Underkända: " + str(tasksundk))
    time.sleep(1)
    punkt2_i1()


def punkt2_i1():
    toplabel = Label(root, text="blablabla", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), width=39, background="#414141",
                     foreground="#878AFF")
    toplabel.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=40, ipadx=40)

    procent_label = Label(root, text="0%", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 50), height=1, width=22, background="#414141",
                          foreground="#878AFF")
    procent_label.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=0, ipadx=40)

    task_label = Label(root, text="...", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=2, width=39, background="#414141",
                       foreground="#878AFF")
    task_label.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=0, ipadx=40)

    status_godk = Label(root, text="Godkända: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=12,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_godk.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=1, pady=40, sticky="w")

    status_undk = Label(root, text="Underkända: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=16,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_undk.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=1, pady=40, padx=40)

    status_kvar = Label(root, text="Kvar: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=10,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_kvar.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=1, pady=40, sticky="e")

    avsluta = Button(root, text="AVSLUTA", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), cursor="hand2", height=0, width=39,
                     border=0, foreground="#878AFF", background="#414141", activebackground="#999999",
                     activeforeground="#D3D5FF", relief="sunken")
    avsluta.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=(0, 40), ipadx=40)
    global tasksleft
    global tasksgodk
    global tasksundk
    for line in bromsdata:
        if "huvudledningstryck" in line:
            break
    huvudlindex = (line.find("="))
    huvudltryckindex = int(huvudlindex) + 1
    hlt = line[huvudltryckindex:]
    hlt = int(hlt.strip())
    print(hlt)
    if hlt > 62:
        print("fail")
        tasksundk = tasksundk + 1
    elif hlt < 44:
        print("fail")
        tasksundk = tasksundk + 1
    else:
        print("Success")
        tasksgodk = tasksgodk + 1
    tasksleft = tasksleft - 1

    task_label.configure(text="Just nu pågår: 4.0.3 Kontroll av Huvudbehållartryck...")
    procent_label.config(text="66%")
    status_kvar.configure(text="Kvar: " + str(tasksleft))
    status_godk.configure(text="Godkända: " + str(tasksgodk))
    status_undk.configure(text="Underkända: " + str(tasksundk))
    time.sleep(1)
    punkt3_i1()


def punkt3_i1():
    toplabel = Label(root, text="blablabla", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), width=39, background="#414141",
                     foreground="#878AFF")
    toplabel.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=40, ipadx=40)

    procent_label = Label(root, text="0%", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 50), height=1, width=22, background="#414141",
                          foreground="#878AFF")
    procent_label.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=0, ipadx=40)

    task_label = Label(root, text="...", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=2, width=39, background="#414141",
                       foreground="#878AFF")
    task_label.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=0, ipadx=40)

    status_godk = Label(root, text="Godkända: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=12,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_godk.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=1, pady=40, sticky="w")

    status_undk = Label(root, text="Underkända: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=16,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_undk.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=1, pady=40, padx=40)

    status_kvar = Label(root, text="Kvar: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=10,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_kvar.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=1, pady=40, sticky="e")

    avsluta = Button(root, text="AVSLUTA", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), cursor="hand2", height=0, width=39,
                     border=0, foreground="#878AFF", background="#414141", activebackground="#999999",
                     activeforeground="#D3D5FF", relief="sunken")
    avsluta.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=(0, 40), ipadx=40)
    global tasksleft
    global tasksgodk
    global tasksundk
    for line in bromsdata:
        if "huvudbehallartryck" in line:
            break
    huvudbindex = (line.find("="))
    huvudbtryckindex = int(huvudbindex) + 1
    hbt = line[huvudbtryckindex:]
    hbt = int(hbt.strip())
    print(hbt)
    if hbt > 12:
        print("fail")
        tasksundk = tasksundk + 1
    elif hbt < 8:
        print("fail")
        tasksundk = tasksundk + 1
    else:
        print("Success")
        tasksgodk = tasksgodk + 1
    tasksleft = tasksleft - 1

    procent_label.config(text="100%")
    task_label.configure(text="INSPEKTION KLAR")
    status_kvar.configure(text="Kvar: " + str(tasksleft))
    status_godk.configure(text="Godkända: " + str(tasksgodk))
    status_undk.configure(text="Underkända: " + str(tasksundk))


def inspektera_click():
    print("inspect!")



    toplabel = Label(root, text="blablabla", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), width=39, background="#414141",
                     foreground="#878AFF")
    toplabel.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=40, ipadx=40)

    procent_label = Label(root, text="0%", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 50), height=1, width=22, background="#414141",
                          foreground="#878AFF")
    procent_label.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=0, ipadx=40)

    task_label = Label(root, text="...", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=2, width=39, background="#414141",
                       foreground="#878AFF")
    task_label.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=0, ipadx=40)

    status_godk = Label(root, text="Godkända: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=12,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_godk.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=1, pady=40, sticky="w")

    status_undk = Label(root, text="Underkända: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=16,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_undk.grid(row=4, column=2, columnspan=1, pady=40, padx=40)

    status_kvar = Label(root, text="Kvar: ", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), height=1, width=10,
                        background="#414141", foreground="#878AFF")
    status_kvar.grid(row=4, column=3, columnspan=1, pady=40, sticky="e")

    avsluta = Button(root, text="AVSLUTA", font=("Bell Gothic Std Black", 28), cursor="hand2", height=0, width=39,
                     border=0, foreground="#878AFF", background="#414141", activebackground="#999999",
                     activeforeground="#D3D5FF", relief="sunken")
    avsluta.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=3, pady=(0, 40), ipadx=40)

inspektera_click()
t1= threading.Thread(target=starta_i1)
t1.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The problem is the thread. You can't put tkinter calls in a child thread (except a rare few, like event_generate).

Comment: Use `root.after` instead of `threading` + `time.sleep()`.

Comment: Isnt removing threading gonna lead to tkinter freezing? but thanks, ill try it later today :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use root.after instead of threading:

```
def starta_i1():
    ...
    root.after(1000, punkt1_i1) # wait 1 second, then call punkt1_i1()

def punkt1_i1():
    ...
    root.after(1000, punkt2_i1) # wait 1 second, then call punkt2_i1()

def punkt2_i1():
    ...
    root.after(1000, punkt3_i1) # wait 1 second, then call punkt3_i1()

def punkt3_i1():
    ...

inspektera_click()
starta_i1() # start first function

root.mainloop()
```